# how to transfer dynamic element data to struts2

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2

I am developing a online test website using jsp. One of my pages is used to design test paper online. The user can add questions dynamically and then store it to database. I think I can use a JavaScript instance to store these information. But how can I transfer such data to Struts 2 to store the paper to database? Or should I use some other means to store the questions and interact with Struts2

Comment: It's very hard to  answer to such a general question, so i'll be posting a general answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the correct attributes to your dynamically generated html elements.